# How KafKa guarantee Consistency and Availability?

Tags: distributed-computing, apache-kafka, distributed-system

I learned from http://engineering.linkedin.com/kafka/intra-cluster-replication-apache-kafka

> Our goal was to support replication in a Kafka cluster within a single datacenter, where network partitioning is rare

In the Distributed system, I think "Partitioning" is basic, so I don't know Kafka guarantee the availability without partition when only server node failed. Or I miss something

Answer (score 8):

I think you may be confusing the sharding sense of "partitioning" with network partitions.

Kafka does indeed provide sharding and replication. Kafka elects a unique leader for each partition of each topic. All writes for a topic partition go through the leader. This is relevant to the documentation you cited indicating Kafka favor's availability over partition tolerance.

What is meant by network partitions is a break in communication between servers. Network communication failures are more rare in a LAN than in a WAN, so Kafka was architected to provide consistency except in cases where a network partition occurs. In the event of a network partition, Kafka's replicas may diverge from one another, with nodes on both sides of the partition potentially accepting writes. The reason this may occur is because when a network partition happens, nodes on each side of the partition can perceive nodes on the other side of the partition as having failed when in fact the link between them only failed. This means that each side of the network partition may elect a new leader for some topic partitions, therefore meaning that each side of the network partition can accept writes for some topic partitions. Once the network partition heals (the network is fixed), writes made on one side of the partition may overwrite writes made on the other side of the partition.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, kuujo, I summary from your answer, for example, there two network side(side a, side  b),  when a topic x made three partitions in the two network side(p1 is in side a, p2, p3 is in side b) and p1 is leader of this topic. so when network between side a and side b broken, p2, p3 must elect the leader in the side b for the topic, and p1 still is leader in the side a for the topic. So two writes has happened for the topic,  and consistency is not guaranteed. Is that right?